# Ordering objects  in r based on their relationships

Tags: r, dataframe, permutation

I have a data frame containing 3 objects (A,B,C) that have the following relationship scores:

```
relationships<-data.frame(object.1=c("A","A","B"),object.2=c("B","C","C"),relationship=1:3)

relationships

  object.1 object.2 relationship
1        A        B            1
2        A        C            2
3        B        C            3
```

Consider all possible permutations of A,B,C and the relationship scores between adjacent objects i.e.

```
A   1   B   3   C   = 4
A   2   C   3   B   = 5
C   2   A   1   B   = 3
B   1   A   2   C   = 3
B   3   C   2   A   = 5
C   3   B   1   A   = 4
```

I need to identify the order of the objects which orders the objects so that the relationships of adjacent objects are as high as possible going from left to right i.e. for the example above I would select

```
B   3   C   2   A   = 5
```

Any suggestions how I should go about this? Thanks.

Comment: You could find a maximum for `relationship` and if you have several, see which one has maximum at `A`, then at `B` and finally if still a tie, at `C`.

Answer (score 1):

Is this close to what you're looking for?

```
library(data.table)
relationships<-data.table(object.1=c("A","A","B"),object.2=c("B","C","C"),relationship=1:3)
relationships<-rbindlist(list(relationships,relationships[,list(object.1=object.2, object.2=object.1, relationship)]))
setkey(relationships,object.1,object.2)

perm<-CJ(C1=LETTERS[1:3],C2=LETTERS[1:3],C3=LETTERS[1:3])[!C1==C2 & !C1==C3 & !C2==C3]
setkey(perm,C1,C2)
perm[relationships,rel.1:=relationship]
setkey(perm,C2,C3)
perm[relationships,rel.2:=relationship]
perm[order(-rel.1,-rel.2)]
```

It's not very extensible as it is, but maybe it could be extended...

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be shortest path in a graph problem (i.e. longest, but this doesn't matter) -- try to use `igraph` to treat your input as a real graph, then use `shortest.paths` to find optimal connections, finally select this which realizes your decreasing relationship criterion best. (It is sub-optimal solution, but the optimal would likely require writing this in C or something like that).